# Setting Default Values to Drop Down in Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: dropdown, orbeon

I have a autocomplete field:

[image: image1]

I need to set the default value selected for this dropdown using another control value as shown in:

[image: image2]

This control is passed to the form load as shown in:

[image: image 3]

For example if use cost center is `110` as shown in:

[image: image 4]([![https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wlqR.png]

Then the default selected value of the Site lookup dropdown needs to be as shown in:

[image: image 5]

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is that your `Site-Item` field isn't a dropdown but an autocomplete. An autocomplete doesn't know all the possible label/values, but can only find some label/values doing a search by label. So you can't tell an autocomplete "set your value to 110", because it doesn't know what the label corresponding to `110` is.

If you knew the label, you could do this programmatically [with an `fr-set-label`](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/autocomplete#setting-by-label), but here you don't have the label but the value. You can read more about this in the section [Setting by value](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/autocomplete#setting-by-value). So, my advice is to use a Dynamic Data Dropdown instead of an Autocomplete field.

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you please help me to set the initial/default value for a dynamic drop down then, please also note that this `Site-Item` Auto complete field should have the search/filter facility too. Ex: Even though the initial selected value of `Site-Item` should correspond to `AWHCCENTER` field, user needs to search and select another value from Site-Item` drop down if needed. Please help. Thank you

Comment: @n.path The Dynamic Data Dropdown doesn't have a search capability; it renders as a plain dropdown. Of course, on most browsers users can click on the dropdown and then use the keyboard to search for or select a value (as they can on any dropdown). Does this make sense, or did I misunderstand your last comment?

Comment: @n.path Did you get a chance to try using the Dynamic Data Dropdown to handle this use case? If so, did it work out, or did you hit some problem along the way?